# How to change DNS Records url to point from (example.com/page1) to (page1.example.com)?

Tags: javascript, html, dns

I Just brought a domain lets say **"example.com"**.

And I pointed an adobe portfolio website that I made to that domain in the A record.

Lets say every time I access **"example.portfolio.adobe.com" I'm in "example.com**".
So far so good.

Adobe doesn't let me change the html of the portfolio :(

Now I have a specific page that I want to add to the portfolio **page1** on tumblr.

**page1.tumblr.com.**

I want to mask redirect "example.com/page1" to "page1.tumblr.com".

name.com doesn't let me to do this, it says example.com/page1 is invalid but it lets me change **"page1.example.com" to "page1.tumblr.com"**

Is there any way it can be done, in DNS records or javascript or Its just impossible to change the record to have my page going from "example.com/page1" to "page1.tumblr.com"?
(basically everytime I access "example.com/page1" I want to display the content of "page1.tumblr.com")

Comment: I'm very confused. Are you saying that there's a CORS error between your site and the new page1 site?

Comment: DNS records deal with domain names to ip address ... so DNS won't fix your issue